# Linux- Breaking up a large JSON file into chunks to minify

Tags: json, compression

I am working with a 6.0 MB JSON file that is being used with about 100 other scripts on a server that will soon be set up. I wish to compress the file by deleting all of the extra spaces, tabs, returns, etc., but all of the sources I've found for compressing the file can't handle the file's size (it's around 108,000 lines of code). I need to break the file up in a way that it will be easy to reassemble once each chunk has been compressed. Does anyone know how to break it up in an efficient way? Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is using a nodeJS command an option? If so take a look at https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because python scripts could already handle the large file, I ended up using ipython and writing a .py script that would dump the script without spaces. To use this script, one would type:

```
$ ipython -i compression_script.py
```

This is the code within compression_script.py:

```
import json
filename=  raw_input('Enter the file you wish to compress: ')# file name we want to compress
newname = 'compressed_' + filename   # by default i have set the new filename to be 'compressed_' + filename
fp = open(filename)
jload = json.load(fp)
newfile = json.dumps(jload, indent = None, separators = (',', ':')) 
f = open(newname, 'wb')
f.write(newfile)
f.close()
print('Compression complete! Type quit to exit IPython')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can be done in php also like ....

```
//
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$handle = fopen("somehugefile.json", "r");
if ($handle) {
  $i = 0;
  while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle, 5096);
    $buffer = str_replace("\r\n","", $buffer);
    $buffer = str_replace("\t","", $buffer);
    fwrite($myfile, $buffer);
    $i++;
    //var_dump($buffer);
    /*
    if ($i == 1000) {
      die('stop');
    }
    */
  }
  fclose($handle);
  fclose($myfile);
}
```